# Custom select dropdown needs 2 clicks in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, combobox, safari, dropdown

Good morning/afternoon/whatever.

I am having issues with a custom combobox/datalist made in React, and how it behaves in Safari. In chrome it behaves how it is meant to. The user clicks once on the text input to display the dropdown, and once more on the option from the dropdown to select the option.

The problem is that in Safari, there is another click that is needed. The user clicks on the text input to display the dropdown, and then **the second click only focuses on the dropdown**, and a third click is then needed to actually select the option from the dropdown selection.

Below is a basic demonstration of what I am working with, but it is not everything, obviously.

```
showDropdown() {
    if (this.props.options.length < 11) {
        this.dropdown.size = this.props.options.length;
    } else { this.dropdown.size = 11; }
}

hideDropdown() {
    this.dropdown.size = 0;
}

render() {
    const dropdown = (
        <select
            ref={c => { this.dropdown = c; }}
            id={`${this.props.id}_dropdown`}
            value={this.state.value}

            onFocus={this.showDropdown}
            onBlur={this.hideDropdown}
            tabIndex="-1"
        >
            {listToTimeField(this.props.options)}
        </select>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                ref={c => { this.input = c; }}
                name={`${this.props.name}_input`}
                value={this.state.input_value}

                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onChange={this.handleEdit}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            />
            <div className="dropdown_container">
                {dropdown}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this code runs well on most platforms, with the notable exception of Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Possibly not the most efficient solution though.

I added an onClick handler to the dropdown that reads the value of the element that it's clicked on, and assigns that value to the dropdown.

```
dropdownClick(e) {
    if (this.dropdown.size > 0
    && this.dropdown.value !== e.target.value) {
        this.dropdown.value = e.target.value;
    }
    this.hideDropdown();
}
```

This almost solved the issue completely, however, if you scrolled down the dropdown and then clicked on it, it would go back to the 3 clicks behavior. To resolve this I added another handler for onScroll.

```
onScroll={e => e.target.focus()}
```

Which means that the dropdown goes in focus on scroll, and eliminated the 3 click behavior on scroll.

Now, whether you scroll or not, there is only 2 clicks ever needed to open and select an option from this custom dropdown.